# How to force emmake use config.h file and do preprocess?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, emscripten

I'm trying to build project with emscripten(latest) and I've done emconfigure ./configure. And now trying to do emmake make. But it can't find new.h file which required in a preprocess directive, i'm sure that native configuration makes a good config file. And it compiles with native make. So the question is how to make emmake do preprocessing correct?

```
#if defined(UNDER_CE)
# ifndef __WCEALT_H__
inline void * operator new(size_t, void * ptr) { return ptr; }
# endif
#elif defined(AUTOCONF) && defined(HAVE_STDINCLUDES)
# include <new>
#else
# include <new.h>
#endif
```

PS: Maybe somebody know how to do preprocessing before compilation? To remove useless code? Something like `g++ -e` or similar, but I can't find a good workflow with huge project.

PS: Output emmake:

```
libtool: compile:  /Users/tau0/reader/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.16.0/em++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I. -DNDEBUG -Wall -O3 -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -c GOS.cpp  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/GOS.o
In file included from GOS.cpp:63:
In file included from ./GException.h:120:
./DjVuGlobal.h:72:11: fatal error: 'new.h' file not found
# include <new.h>
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emconfigure disables stl by default, so check your new config.h for HAVE_STDINCLUDES.